# How do we differentiate homotopies?

Tags: analysis, differential-topology, homotopy-theory

The problem setting is the following: we have two functions, $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ and $g:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$, $0\leq\lambda\leq 1$, $f^{\prime}(t) > 0$, $g^{\prime}(t) > 0$, $f(0) = 0$, $f(1) = g(1) = 1$ and $f^{\prime}(t)\geq g^{\prime}(t)$. Then consider a homotopy between $f$ and $g$: $H:[0,1]\times\Lambda\rightarrow[0,1]$ such that $H(t,0) = g(t)$ and $H(t,1) = f(t)$. My question is: how do we differentiate $\lambda H$ with respect to $\lambda$ and $t$?

Comment: Take an example of a homotopy, maybe trivial ones. Then differentiation turns out to be not complex at all

Comment: I am interested in differentiating homotopies without an explicit expression. Otherwise, I am able to handle it.

Comment: Then apply the chain rule. Based on examples $\lambda$ can be included in many ways. Therefore chain rule should work quite well

Comment: Could you provide a detailed answer?

Comment: I just realized I totally do not understand your notation. In my answer, I used $s$ as the homotopy parameter, but I'm guessing you mean it to be $\lambda$. What do you mean by $\lambda H$? I thought you were multiplying by the parameter $\lambda$; do you have something else in mind? I'm going to edit to put $\lambda$ in as the homotopy parameter as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathcal H(\lambda, t) = \lambda H(t,\lambda)$. Then
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial\mathcal H}{\partial \lambda} &= H(t,\lambda) + \lambda\frac{\partial H}{\partial\lambda} \qquad\text{and} \\
\frac{\partial\mathcal H}{\partial t} & = \lambda\frac{\partial H}{\partial t}.\end{align*}
If we don't know the homotopy, that's all we can say. If you took the straight-line homotopy between the functions, we'd have
$H(t,\lambda) = \lambda f(t)+(1-\lambda)g(t)$, and then we could say $\dfrac{\partial H}{\partial \lambda} = \lambda f'(t)+(1-\lambda)g'(t)$, and then you obtain $\dfrac{\partial\mathcal H}{\partial\lambda}$ by substitution.